# Using same class object in another function

Tags: function, class, using

My Code is Like This

public function function1(){

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setAccessToken('Some value');

}

public funnction function2(){

// Here I want to get the token using $client->getAccessToken()

}

How can use the same instance of class from function1 in function2? So I can use $client->getAccessToken() in function2

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution use `global`

```
<?php

    $client;

    function function1(){
        global $client;
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAccessToken('Some value');
    }

    function function2(){
        global $client;
        $token=$client->getAccessToken();
    }
?>
```

It's simple but not recommended. It's never a good Idea to use a global variables, we must avoid it as long as possible.
So there must be some other way,right ?
well yes use `class`

```
<?php

class ForClient {

    private $client;

    function __construct(){
        $client = new Google_Client();
    }

    public function setToken($val){
        $client->setAccessToken($val);
    }

    public function getToken(){
        $token=$client->getAccessToken();
        return $token;
    }
 }

$token_handler = new ForClient(); 
$token_handler->setToken(25);
$token=$token_handler->getToken();
?>
```

I changed the function names to make code more readable.